# How to multiply array of doubles in another double?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to this site, and am working on a school assignment, but got stuck.
 I was wondering if there is any way to multiply a `double []array` by a `double`?

```
for(int i = 0; i <= speed.length; i++)
    double [] mph = speed[i] * 1.15;
```

That is my code, but when I compile it in java, it says:

> `"Incompatible types: double cannot be converted to double[]"`

How do I fix this?

Comment: mph[i]=speed[i] * 1.15, you are trying to assign a double to a array var

Comment: Is that not allowed?

Comment: double [] mph = new double[speed.length], before your loop, and in your loop you fill this array

Comment: You have to multiply each element separately by the scalar factor. Arrays are not vectors, and do not support any vectorial operation

Comment: @Dici without a library, no, but... http://nd4j.org

Comment: I think what you want to do is create an array `mph` which corresponds, index-to-index, to `speed`.

Comment: @cricket_007 that won't change the fact arrays are not vectors. You would have to implement a separate compiler for this

Comment: @cricket_007 these are not arrays anymore if they are wrapped into a class... So you can never say that Java arrays have vectorial operations

Comment: @Maya learn about arrays [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) and about basic data types [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm), a double is not array of doubles, thats why get that message.

Comment: @RahmatWaisi not really... he's getting the message because the `*` operator is only supported for scalar types

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!!! It works :)

Comment: @Dici Are you sure?  It looks like `speed[i]` is a double, `1.15` is a double, they're multiplied.  Then the result, a double, is assigned to... `double mph[]`, an array of doubles.  Looks to me like Rahmat is right?

Comment: @Arjan yep obviously ! Sorry dude when I see such questions I tend to parse the text so hastily that I start stating non-sense like this :p You're right of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:
you need to be a little more specific about where the result of the operation is going to be stored...

you have the Array speed so yo can use this to store directly the result...

for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < speed.length; i++)
    speed[i] = speed[i] * 1.15;
```

you can define a new array... like the one named **mph**, just be careful with the size of the new one... 
and then do:

```
double mph[] = new double[speed.length];
for(int i = 0; i < speed.length; i++)
    mph[i] = speed[i] * 1.15;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was so confused and didn't know how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to watch out for is the `i <= speed.length` condition in your for loop. When you try to edit the value for when `i == speed.length`, you'll get an array out of bounds exception, because you are trying to edit a value outside of the `speed` array. The maximum index in `speed` is equal to `speed.length - 1`. Because of this, you should change it to `i < speed.length`.